# Extract the first line of text in tableau

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I need to extract the first line of text in tableau. I tried using Regex Replace function but I couldn't get the desired output.

**Given below is the input.**

Name:

ABC DEF LTD

GONZALEZ, Henry

**Desired output:**

ABC DEF LTD

What I tried:
Regex_Replace('Column_name','

','')

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try a non-regex approach. First convert the carriage return / line feed to a pipe (or some other symbol of your choosing. Your space may be CHAR(10) or could be CHAR(13)...or perhaps you have both. This example shows using CHAR(13):

```
[RemoveSpace]: replace([Name],CHAR(13),"|")
```

You want to keep the first line, so use this calc:

```
[KeepFirstLine]: SPLIT([RemoveSpace],"|",1)
```

Comment: Andy, I was dumb. This works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Converting the new lines to pipes and then extracting the first word before the pipe was easier.

Answer (score 1):

This should match first line with a at least one word character.

```
^.*\w+.*$
```

- `^` start of line
- `.*` any character except newline zero or more times
- `\w+` any word character one or more times
- `.*` any character except newline zero or more times
- `$` end of line

Comment: I applied this and the result is NULL

Comment: Are you using right method for this? I am not a user of tableu but Regex_Replace seems to be used for replacing, not extract? Or do maybe you retrive the value after replacing?
There is another method called `REGEXP_EXTRACT`

Comment: Yes, I did use REGEXP_EXTRACT and Null was the result of it.